# Transparent iFrame: shows text/content on the underlying page's background

Tags: css, html, iframe

I am creating a web/mobile app and I would like to be able to display the contents of page1 (page1 is HTML and contains text buttons sliders, images) in an  on page2 with opacity=.5 so that the contents of page1 displays on the background image of page2.
The problem is that if I set the background of page1 to transparent, then nothing is displayed (page1 looks like white on white on its own, and shows nothing when displayed over page2).  If I set the background of page1 = black, then its content displays over the background of page2, but this creates 50% darkening of the background of page2.  I haven't been able to figure this out from other SO pages on iframe backgrounds, which there are a number of.

Thanks for your help

FYI, this is an approach to put iframe content into a Famo.us front-end that can use JS to set the opacity level of the surface for the iframe where page1 is.

Comment: have you tried adding allowTransparency="true" to the iframe?

Comment: Unfortunately, tried this but it did not work.

Comment: do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ach6mrj3/1/

Comment: Thanks fgshepard, this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach:

first load the page1 in iframe

then declare a div and set itrs potion to absolute height &width 100%
and background rgba(0,0,0,.1)

inside this div put your page two contents.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html >
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://somesource" ></iframe>
        <div id="box">
            <h2>page 2 contents goes here ...</h2>
        </div>
        <style >
            #box{
                position:absolute;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                top:0; left:0;
                background:rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            }
        </style>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Hope this Helps**